# White Box Testing vs Trace Tables

Tags: testing

I've seen [trace tables](http://www.101computing.net/trace-table/) listed under white-box testing in one part of my syllabus, and separately under dry-run testing in another part. Could anyone please clarify whether trace tables are generally considered to be part of one or both types of testing?

I have researched this thoroughly and found nothing that addresses this ambiguity.
For example in:
http://www.101computing.net/trace-table/

and

http://theteacher.info/index.php/2-3-producing-robust-programs/notes/5287-the-purpose-of-testing

Trace tables are listed as a dry-run technique.

The syllabus (http://www.cambridgeinternational.org/images/202629-2017-2019-syllabus.pdf) contains an ambiguity which I wish to get some help with clarifying for my students.

Comment: please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536835/white-box-testing-vs-trace-tables

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/92338/755, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/371594/34181, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50536835/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **trace table** is a nothing but a line-by-line log including line numbers of the source code and variable content. This is obviously a **white-box** technique, since it is strongly coupled to the implementation internals of each method under test. It is a very old testing (and debugging) technique, I guess >40 years old, intended for procedural code, and your links still mention it as a technique often done using pencil and paper. Today people typically utilize a debugger and step through the code line-by-line or statement-by-statement, using the debugger's tracing and monitoring features.

The term **dry-run** is not that strictly defined, but in context of your links, it probably means to take out some piece of code out of a bigger program and run it with some manageable input data. "Executing" it using a piece of paper is also mentioned, but IMHO not necessarily part of the definition of the term "dry-run". This is also a very old terminology and approach, with a similar age like the former. The modern equivalent is **unit tests**, which makes dry-runs painless, repeatable and effective, without any need for pencil and paper.

Now, unit tests can be used in conjunction with stepping through the code using a debugger, this is an effective technique for understanding what the code does, especially when searching for an error. It is often more effective than using the debugger in context of a complex program. However, unit tests are also (and actually more often) used without a debugger, these usages are orthogonal.

This holds even more for trying to utilize a trace table on paper: in context of a large, complex section of code, this becomes quickly unmanageable. So it is better to use it in context of a dry-run scenario.

So in short

- using a trace table (or step-by-step debugging) is always a white-box testing technique
- a trace table is most effective in a dry-run scenario (or a unit test), but this is not a mandatory connection, and not part of it's definition

As a final remark: a syllabus which mentions dry-run testing, but not unit testing as a basic testing technique, would probably get improved by an update.

Comment: Thank you. "using a trace table (or step-by-step debugging) is always a white-box testing technique" is exactly what I was looking for, My confusion came from this line in the syllabus: "show understanding of the methods of testing available: dry run, walkthrough, white-box,
black-box, integration, alpha, beta, acceptance" where trace-tables and white-box are listed separately.

Comment: @Robin: this is a syllabus, telling people the planned content of the courses, that list is not a disjoint categorization.

Answer (score 0):

Donald Firesmith, from SEI, had a great essay on the [Taxonomy of Testing](https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/sei_blog/2015/08/a-taxonomy-of-testing.html), and trace tables are not listed (the list is exhaustive, but might be out of date). You get the full [slides here](https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetid=450418) (they're a must for any SW developer).

I consider trace tables as **test evidences**, and they are applicable to multiple testing types, not just whitebox. So, trace tables are not a test-type, but a test-artifact.

You could also get in contact with Donald Firesmith and get his take on this.

Comment: You must have a very different form of trace table in mind than the OP when saying they are also applicable to non-white-box-tests.

Comment: I have used, for example, actual DB tables as trace tables, and populate the DB tables from triggers or other observation patterns instrumented from outside the application source code. Once you have your trace tables generated, then you would verify the right steps were done in the right sequence, o simply compare them with SQL against other tables which already have the expected results.